# Finding the maximum elements in an NSArray (or NSMutableArray)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I am having a bit of trouble navigating around an `NSArray`.

My array:

```
Element[0] = "ElementA"
Element[1] = "ElementA"
Element[2] = "ElementA"
Element[3] = "ElementA"
Element[4] = "ElementB"
Element[5] = "ElementC"
```

Are there any methods in Objective-C that will help me find the "median" element? In this case, the "median" would be "ElementA", or the value that occurs the maximum number of times.

In C# this would be a single call, but I can't find an equivalent in Objective-C.

Many thanks,
Brett

Comment: That's not the median.  Median is synonymous with "average".  What you're looking for is the "mode".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrote this just for you :)

```
- (NSString *) findModeString: (NSArray *) array {
   NSMutableDictionary *stats = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
   for(NSString *str in array) {
      if(![stats objectForKey:str]) {
         [stats setObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:str];
      } else {
         [stats setObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[stats objectForKey:str] intValue] + 1] forKey:str];
      }
   }
   NSInteger maxOccurrences = 0;
   NSString *max;
   for(NSString *key in stats) {
      if([[stats objectForKey:key] intValue] > maxOccurrences) {
         max = key;
         maxOccurrences = [[stats objectForKey:key] intValue];
      }
   }
   [stats release];
   return max;
}
```

**EDIT**: Although my solution works, you should upvote/accept [@Dave DeLong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115730/dave-delong)'s answer, it is much much better.

Comment: Wow...serious kudos! Awesome, and much simpler than I had anticipated. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 8):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
NSArray * elements = ...; //your array of elements:
NSCountedSet * counts = [NSCountedSet setWithArray:elements]:
id modeObject = nil;
NSUInteger modeCount = 0;
for (id element in counts) {
  if ([counts countForObject:element] > modeCount) {
    modeCount = [counts countForObject:element];
    modeObject = element;
  }
}

NSLog(@"element with highest frequency: %@", modeObject);
```

An `NSCountedSet` is an `NSMutableSet` that also remembers how many times its elements have been added to the array.

Comment: @Dave I knew there was something like that, but I couldn't find it! Nice! +1

Comment: This will work with any object, not just `NSString`. Awesome.

Comment: Yeah, `NSCountedSet` is one of those little hidden gems that's hardly ever useful, but when you need it, it's perfect. :)

Comment: hi it would have count of repetition of actual object or  object with same value also be counted ???????

Comment: @pawan.mangal objects are considered equal if `[obj1 isEqual:obj2]` returns `YES` (and this is what `NSSet` and friends are using).  The default implementation on `NSObject` simply does pointer comparison (and therefore is testing actual objects).  However, `NSString` overrides it do be more like `strcmp()`, so in that case it would test equal values.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use:

```
[myarray length] /2
```

Comment: that would give me the number of elements divided by 2. What I am looking for is a method that shows me the value of the most occurred element. In this example, the value would be "ElementA".

Comment: Sorry - I meant - you sort the array and then do that.

Comment: This techniques is sound and easy.